# How to edit components and provide our own components in alfresco digital workspace

Tags: angular, alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

I previously have worked with [Alfresco-ACA](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-content-app), which has the proper angular folder structure and i was able to add my custom components and modules into it, where as i was asked to upgrade to [Alfresco-Digital-Workspace](https://docs.alfresco.com/adw/concepts/welcome-adw.html), on getting the basic zip of **adf-governance-app-1.0.0.zip** and **digital-workspace-1.3.0.zip**,

When i unzip it i couldn't get the folder structure as of ACA
I even went through the documentation of [ADW-Site](https://alfresco-content-app.netlify.com/#/). Please guide me with some steps on how to install the adw in my local to start development

P.S : Used npm install and npm start. seems like server is not up

Answer (score 1):

ADW is based on ACA and you should see something similar, especially when you try to launch it.

Did you properly configure the app.config.json?

What is the error you have after the launch (see the console of the browser).

Feel free to ask for a support also on the gitter channel at https://gitter.im/Alfresco/content-app

[alfresco](/questions/tagged/alfresco)[workspace](/questions/tagged/workspace)[adw](/questions/tagged/adw)

Comment: please add some tags so people with specific domain knowledge can answer your question.

Comment: @francesco when i checked with support team, they suggested saying ADW is simply an overlay of the underlying ACA. You can use the attached governance extension as an example of how to write your own extensions. The documentation for ACA is applicable for ADW development as well: https://alfresco-content-app.netlify.com/#/extending/  But, normally when im trying to build/ start the application of digital-workspace-1.3.0.zip the team provided im unable to start it

Comment: the src folder is not containing folder structure as of content-app(ACA), ADW is just having 3 files (app.actions-order.json, plugins.json, tsconfig.json)

Comment: @ Srikanth what the support says is correct, but you are having a problem launching the app, not customizing the app. Again: What is the error that you see after the launch? (see the console of the browser).